# partial string returned as field value mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I am getting **incomplete** string value from mysql query result. It appears that when the string is too long, the value is **sliced**. I am fetching the value as a `JSON` string. There is no issue with my local database, no matter how long the field value is.

Here's my query:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`devdbuser`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetTrainingFilesByID`(IN trainingID int)
BEGIN  
  SELECT t1.*, concat(t2.firstname,' ',t2.lastname) as username
  FROM users t2
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT t.*,
    CONCAT('[',
          GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{"id":"',d.id,
                               '","name":"', d.title, 
                               '","file_path":"',d.doc_path,
                               '","is_video":"',d.is_video,'"}'
                              )), ']'
          ) files 
          FROM training t 
          LEFT JOIN training_documents d 
          ON t.id = d.training_id 
          GROUP BY t.id
  ) t1
  ON t1.updated_by = t2.id
  WHERE t1.id = trainingID
  LIMIT 1;
  END
```

The issue is with `files` field value.

Here's the `incomplete` output:

```
"[{"id":"1", "name":"Branch Workflow Model for GBD_1.pdf", "file_path":"1455443689.pdf", "is_video":"0"},
  {"id":"2", "name":"http://192.168.11.32/GBD-Videos/testvideo.mp4", "file_path":"http://192.168.11.32/GBD-Videos/testvideo.mp4", "is_video":"1"},
  {"id":"6", "name":"COD-CC-CrowdWisdom-Report-exclusive_mybigcommerce_com-2018_09_26-05_28_58.pdf", "file_path":"1862665875.pdf", "is_video":"0"},
  {"id":"7", "name":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCAIY5n1hPA.mp4", "file_path":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCAIY5n1hPA.mp4", "is_video":"1"},
  {"id":"8", "name":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCAIY5n1hP1.mp4", "file_path":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCAIY5n1hP1.mp4", "is_video":"1"},
  {"id":"19", "name":"Branch Workflow Model for GBD.docx", "file_path":"1250685453.docx", "is_video":"0"},
  {"id":"20", "name":"COK_CorporateMedicineDelivery_Growbydata.pdf", "file_path":"1245383653.pdf", "is_video":"0"},
  {"id":"21", "name":"COK_Intro_Growbydata.pdf", "file_path":"1918218679.pdf", "is_video":"0"},
  {"id":"22", "name":"http:/]"
```

Does mysql have some feature that prevents long field result values? How do I fix this?

Comment: *There is no issue with my local database, no matter how long the field value is* - so are getting this incomplete result from production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its main because you are using group concat. i recommend you to run this query so that it will increase the limit of group concat

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=15000
```

hope this helps. :)